# How do you send mail in Android using JavaMail API?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

How do you send mail from Android? The same code is working fine in a Java project but not in Android.

1) GmailSender.java

```
       import javax.activation.DataHandler;
       import javax.activation.DataSource;
       import javax.mail.Message;
       import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
       import javax.mail.Session;
       import javax.mail.Transport;
       import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
       import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
       import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.InputStream;
       import java.io.OutputStream;
       import java.security.Security;
       import java.util.Properties;

       public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
       private String mailhost ="smtp.gmail.com";
       private String user;
       private String password;
       private Session session;

       static {
       Security.addProvider(new com.idocz.JSSEProvider());
       }

       public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
       this.user = user;
       this.password = password;

       Properties props = new Properties();
       props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
       props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.port","465");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
       "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
       props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

       session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
       }

       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
       return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
       }

       public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender,                                  String recipients) throws Exception {
       MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
       DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(),            "text/plain"));
       message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
       message.setSubject(subject);
       message.setDataHandler(handler);
       if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
       message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,            InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
       else
       message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
       Transport.send(message);
       }

       public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
       private byte[] data;
       private String type;

       public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
       super();
       this.data = data;
       this.type = type;
       }

       public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
       super();
       this.data = data;
       }

       public void setType(String type) {
       this.type = type;
       }

       public String getContentType() {
       if (type == null)
       return "application/octet-stream";
       else
       return type;
       }

       public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
       return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
       }

       public String getName() {
       return "ByteArrayDataSource";
       }

       public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
       throw new IOException("Not Supported");
       }
       }
       }
```

2) JSSEProvider.java

```
        import java.security.AccessController;
        import java.security.Provider;

        public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public JSSEProvider() {
     super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
     AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
         public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}

     GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("xxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx");
     sender.sendMail("Test", "Test mail",  "xxx@gmail.com", "xxx@gmail.com");
```

GMailSender class call in activity class but I got error.

```
     05-07 19:59:42.729: E/dalvikvm(9567): Could not find class 'com.test.GMailSender', referenced from method com.test.sendmail$2.onClick

     05-07 19:59:43.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    05-07 19:59:43.739: E/AndroidRuntime(9567): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.GMailSender
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with sending e-mail. The app is missing your own app. Seems that you made errors while copying code from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/737885
Doesn't your IDE intercept this error?

Comment: solved issus.thanks reply me

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to **add 3 jar** **files in libs folder** which are below

1. [activation.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadactivationjar.htm)
2. [additionnal.jar](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/detail?name=additionnal.jar&can=2&q=)
3. [mail.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmailjar.htm)

After add this code in your application.

Secondly you have to add permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mailsenderactivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("<U R GMAIL ADDRESS>",
                        "<GMAIL PASSWORD>");
                sender.sendMail("This is Subject", "This is Body",
                        "<U R GMAIL (SENDER)>", "<RECIPIENT(RECEIVER) EMAIL ADDRESS>");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Mail Send Successfully.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

GMailSender.java

```
package com.example.mailsenderactivity;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties; 

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
 private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
 private String user;   
 private String password;   
 private Session session;   

static {   
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}   

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler);   
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
    private byte[] data;   
    private String type;   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
  }   
}
```

JSSEProvider.java

```
package com.example.mailsenderactivity;

import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: can u please help me i have same code have added jars as well in lib folder but i am not getting any error my Toast message/log is printed  "Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Mail Send Successfully....."   but i am failed to recieve any email on my provided id here is the SO Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442745/failed-to-send-email-with-smtp-using-android?noredirect=1#comment32357626_21442745

Comment: @Erum i am having the same issue , everything seems to be okay, i get no error , i could see a toast saying message sent successfully but no email recieved .. how did you solved this

Comment: @Addi.Star Sir, have you found a way to receive email?